# For what range of $n$ does improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$ converge

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Here is the improper integral:
$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$$
Determine the range of n to make it converge.

I tried to divide it into two parts:
$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$ + $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$

For the latter part, $\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$. 
According to p-test, obviously when $n>1$, it is converge.

For the former part $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$, I need find the range of n which makes the $\lim_{t \to 0^+}\int_t^1\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$ exist.

Then I have no idea how to do that. Could anybody help me?
Excuse my English. Thanks!

P.S. The answer is $1<n<2$, but how to...

Comment: Note that $\frac{\arctan x}{x}\to 1$ as $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x\to 0^+$

$$\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}\sim\frac x{x^n}=\frac 1{x^{n-1}}$$

and  $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}dx$
 converges for $n-1<1$.

Comment: Not related but I now finally know how to type the asymptotic symbol.

Comment: @Szeto That's good! Refer also to https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols

Comment: Thanks! I’m wondering that for $x\to 0^+$, $\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n} \sim \frac x{x^n}$. But does it still work for the integration from 0 to 1? Because in the integration, there is no condition $x\to 0^+$ I think, instead, the $x$ is a range from 0 to 1. Otherwise, when we calculate $\int_0^1\frac{arctan(x)}{x^n}$, we just calculate $\int_0^1\frac x{x^n}$, which is not correct I think.

Comment: @Alxt For the convergence we can refer to limit comparison test and since $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}dx$ also$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\arctan(x)}{x^n}dx$ cinverges.

Comment: @Alxt Refer also to https://services.math.duke.edu/~cbray/Stanford/2003-2004/Math%2042/limitcomp.pdf

Comment: @gimusi Thank you! The limit comparing theorem. Great!